# Saving multiple different entities with Spring Data Jpa

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have 4 entities, not related to each other and corresponds to its own table. Is there any way I can save/update them with one post call? Lets say there are 4 different components in the frontend that needs to be saved in order if certain criteria is met. I need to make the process transactional, if any of them fails, none of the data should be saved in the db and need to be executed in order.

I am using spring-boot 2.1.6.RELEASE and spring data jpa.

I can save each one of them invidually but I do not see/know anyway I can achieve what I am looking for.

For example:

I can do this

```
public void saveA(EntityA entityA)
aRepository.save(entityA);

public void saveB(EntityB entityB)
bRepository.save(entityB);

public void saveC(EntityC entityC)
cRepository.save(entityC);

public void saveD(EntityD entityD)
dRepository.save(entityD);
```

On my desperation, I was trying the following which obviously didnt work:

```
@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public void save(EntityA entityA,EntityB entityB,EntityC entityC,EntityD entityD)throws Exception{
saveA(entityA);
saveB(entityB);
saveC(entityC);
saveD(entityD);
}
```

If anyone can provide me an example, description or point me to the correct direction. I would really appreciate it.

**UPDATE**

here is my service

```
@Autowired
    EntityARepository aRepository;

    @Autowired
    EntityBRepository bRepository;

    @Autowired
    EntityCRepository cRepository;

    @Autowired
    EntityDRepository dRepository;

    public void saveA(List<EntityA> entityA) {
        aRepository.saveAll(entityA);
    }

    public void saveB(List<EntityB> entityB) {
        bRepository.saveAll(entityB);
    }

    public void saveC(List<EntityC> entityC) {
        cRepository.saveAll(entityC);
    }

    public void saveD(List<EntityD> entityD) {
        dRepository.saveAll(entityD);
    }

    @org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void save(DemoBulkSave demoBulkSave) {
        saveA(demoBulkSave.getEntityA());
        saveB(demoBulkSave.getEntityB());
        saveC(demoBulkSave.getEntityC());
        saveD(demoBulkSave.getEntityD());

    }
```

POJO

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "a")
public class EntityA {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "career")
    private String career;


public class DemoBulkSave {
        List<EntityA> entityA;
        List<EntityB> entityB;
        List<EntityC> entityC;
        List<EntityD> entityD;

        public DemoBulkSave() {
        }

        public List<EntityA> getEntityA() {
            return entityA;
        }

        public void setEntityA(List<EntityA> entityA) {
            this.entityA = entityA;
        }

        public List<EntityB> getEntityB() {
            return entityB;
        }

        public void setEntityB(List<EntityB> entityB) {
            this.entityB = entityB;
        }

        public List<EntityC> getEntityC() {
            return entityC;
        }

        public void setEntityC(List<EntityC> entityC) {
            this.entityC = entityC;
        }

        public List<EntityD> getEntityD() {
            return entityD;
        }

        public void setEntityD(List<EntityD> entityD) {
            this.entityD = entityD;
        }

    }
```

Controller

```
@Autowired
    private EntityService entityService;

    @PostMapping("demo/save")
    public void save(@Valid @RequestBody DemoBulkSave demoBulkSave) throws Exception {
        entityService.save(demoBulkSave);
    }
```

Here is my input Json

```
[
    {
        "firstName": "FName1",
        "lastName": "LName1",
        "career": "career1"
    },
    {
        "firstName": "FName2",
        "lastName": "LName2",
        "career": "career2"
    },
    {
        "firstName": "FName3",
        "lastName": "LName3",
        "career": "career3"
    },
    {
        "firstName": "FName4",
        "lastName": "LName4",
        "career": "career4"
    }
]
```

I am getting the following error while trying to save all 4 entities:

```
"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.example.demo.controller.EntityController$DemoBulkSave` out of START_ARRAY token
```

UPDATE 2
correct POST JSON format

```
{
    "entityA": [
        {
            "firstName": "FName1",
            "lastName": "LName1",
            "career": "career1"
        }
    ],
    "entityB": [
        {
            "firstName": "FName2",
            "lastName": "LName2",
            "career": "career2"
        }
    ],
    "entityC": [
        {
            "firstName": "FName3",
            "lastName": "LName3",
            "career": "career3"
        }
    ],
    "entityD": [
        {
            "firstName": "FName4",
            "lastName":"LName4" ,
            "career": "career4"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: *which obviously didnt work*: how is that obvious? What's your **actual** code (what you posted isn't valid Java code)? Wha did you expect to happen, and what happened instead? Saying "it didn't work" isn't very helpful.

Comment: You can build a `@Service` which holds reference for 4 Repositories. So now, you create generic `save(EntityA a, EntityB b, EntityC C, EntityD D)` and call each Repository as you want to save

Comment: @JBNizet I have updated the question with the details.As I said, I am not sure how it is done, looking for some direction. Thanks

Comment: @Valijon Thank you, i have created DemoBulkSave class and created method in service. Is this the correct way to doing it? I still have some errors due to input. I have updated my question. please take a look.

Comment: Create separated class `DemoBulkSave`. Optionally, `public class DemoBulkSave implements Serializable`. That's correct way, you never should call Repository from  Controller. [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture)

Comment: You're sending a JSON **array**. This array contains four instances of the exact same class. And yet, your controller expects a single object of type DemoBulkSave, containing 4 attributes of type List. So the  JSON and the DemoBulkSave class clearly don't match. You need to send a JSON **object**, with 4 attributes named entityA, entityB, etc., all being arrays. And the entityA rray should contain JSON objects that match with the EntityA class.

Comment: Thank you guys !! it is working now. @Valijon yes, I was just writing the classes on the fly for demo purpose. I wouldn't call repo from controller. @@JBNizet after updating the input format for JSON i was able to save the entities in their respective tables. I have updated the input json format. One question, how can we make sure that these entities are being saved in the order? For example: I want to save EntityA first then B,C and at last D.